# Getting more hardware profiles in to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been looking for some time now for where to obtain and how to import new hardware profiles in to Android Studio, or manually build new ones, but have been unsuccessful.  Can someone point me to a resource that would allow me to do this?  Specifically, I am talking about this area within Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: There are various `HardWare Profile ` see in the Picture or if you have to create `new or like Custom` then click on `New HardWare Profile` and set your `property `  what you have require in that particular `HardWare`.

Comment: you can use genymotion, ignore this bydefault devices.. genymotion is better..   https://www.genymotion.com/  because there is no need for settings.. its automatically configure to your hardware.. only need is your oprating system support virtulization technology..

Comment: Sorry, I left out a few key items here.  First, when I click the New Hardware Profile button, it does nothing.  There is no screen that comes up which allows me to build any new profiles, it simply does nothing.  Second, my goal is to create new devices within Android Studio so I can design against many different screen sizes and densities (which is my reason for wanting to build out new ones).  Regarding Genymotion, I use that already and love it for emulation.

Answer (score 5):

By clicking `New Hardware Profile` it should open a new window like this:

[image]

Here you can change the settings.
If you don't come to this window I think something went wrong during the installing of Android Studio. Maybe you can try to reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: Ok, that would be my issue then.  When I click the button, it does nothing.  I will see if I can change that by reloading Android Studio

Comment: No.  The button to create a new profile does nothing.  I have removed and reloaded Android Studio and still the same issue.

Comment: Okay, great. Now, where do I find the actual information that I can then fill in on this screen?

Comment: Still doesn't show how to add Play Services or use a resizable resolution.

Answer (score 2):

from the main directory see ".android\devices.xml" which contains  entries. For each entry there is an .ini file and an .avd directory. For both the name format is devicename_API_nn ---In each directory there are .ini files and .img files for storage emulation